# Font-face not working from CDN - CORS already set

Tags: firefox, fonts, font-face, cors

I'm having an issue with Firefox where one of my fonts isn't loading from my CDN. I already have Access-Control-Allow-Origin set to *.

The font in question only has WOFF and EOT files (due to licensing) whereas the other font that works has WOFF, EOT, TTF and SVG files.

From what I understand WOFF is supported, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Is there something I'm missing to get this to work?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNovaReg';
    src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-RegWeb.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-RegWeb.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova-RegWeb.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'ProximaNovaSbold';
    src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-SboldWeb.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-SboldWeb.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/ProximaNova-SboldWeb.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your CSS (only the font-face rules)? Do you use `file:///` as URL testing?

Comment: I've updated the question. Not sure what you mean by using file:///. None of these fonts are installed locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing `#iefix` but it looks like it should have been `?#iefix`. I found more information here: [CSS Font Face "?#iefix"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207425/css-font-face-iefix)